# Github Action creates bad Python Manylinux Wheel

Tags: python, github-actions, python-wheel, python-manylinux

I have an incredibly strange problem. I have a Python package that depends on a lot of C++ code. I have set up a Dockerfile that uses the `manylinux_2_24_x86_64` image to create the wheels. Running `docker build` builds the wheels, and I've set up an entrypoint so that `docker run` of the built image copies the wheels to a mounted directory - making them accessible from the outside.

The Dockerfile works when I use it either on a Windows or a Linux host. The generated wheels work fine on Linux (even if the docker image is built on Windows).

*HOWEVER*, and this is the incredibly strange part - I have a github workflow that runs the same Dockerfile, builds the wheels and turns them into a release. These wheels, and only these wheels, are not created properly. They are valid wheel files - I can install them, but when I try them out, I get a segmentation fault.

I'm completely lost, I have no idea how this is even remotely possible - the wheels are built from within the Docker image, and I use the exact same Dockerfile.